# Twitter oAuth : Updating authenticated user's status

Tags: twitter, oauth

I have a web site, that authenticates users using their Twitter ID and password via oAuth.

Everything works well.

I want to know if it's possible to post a status update to the user's Twitter page. I know how to post a status update to my website's Twitter account (which is what the wit web site is registered with), but how do I update someone else's status when they authenticate via my site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [Twitter API Documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc)? There's a [status/update](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) method.

Comment: As I said, I can post status update to the Twitter acount that has the website registered with. But I want to post an update to the user's Twitter account who authenticated with my website. (maybe I'm confusing myself)

Comment: Yep. Turns out I was confused. It's all about setting the access_token correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ebae, the user that authenticated to Twitter from your website has an access_token, so calling status/update method will automatically update his/her account (if access_token is valid).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/) is an example shows how to implement Twitter OAuth with .NET and attached sample code.

It describes user status update after authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize the token for the specific user that will receive the status update. One option is to follow the [PIN-based OAuth method](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based) for sending updates to another user's status.

From the *Implementation* section:

> The PIN-based flow is implemented in the same exact way as
>   Implementing Sign in with Twitter  and 3-legged Authorization, with
>   the only difference being that the value for oauth_callback must be
>   set to oob during the POST oauth / request_token call.
>
> Once your application has obtained either a GET oauth/authenticate or
>   GET oauth/authorize URL, display the URL to the user so that they may
>   use a web browser to access Twitter.
>
> When an oob callback is requested and the user visits Twitter, they
>   will not be automatically redirected to the application upon approving
>   access. Instead, they will see a PIN code, with instructions to return
>   to the application and enter this value.
>
> Your application must allow the user to input this PIN to complete the
>   flow. The PIN code must be passed as the value for oauth_verifier for
>   the POST oauth/access_token request. All other requests will work
>   normally.